# Is there a function to see if the python file is run using "-m pdb"?

Tags: python, pdb

When I use "-m pdb", some code is not working properly. So I want to know if there is a way to see if the file is run using "-m pdb" to choose different method to run my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test with :

```
"pdb" in sys.modules
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was in sys.argv, your answer is totally correct.

Comment: That just checks if `pdb` was imported; it doesn't necessarily indicate that the module is being run as a script.